# Swift - How to get access of constant outside of if statement

Tags: ios, swift

My intention is to create different `UITableViewCells` for a dynamic `UITableView`. I've got the cells set up, I just need to add some logic which cell is to be displayed.

I decided to use an if statement which returns the cell. Somehow this is creating an error, since the `func tableView` needs to return 'cell' as well and code outside of the if statement doesn't have access to `let cell = ..`.

How can I solve this problem?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let date = dateArray[indexPath.row]
        let title = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        let desc = descArray[indexPath.row]

        if notificationType == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TuvTavleViewCell") as! TuvTableViewCell

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewCell") as! NotificationViewCell

            return cell
        }

        cell.setTitle(title: title)
        cell.setDesc(desc: desc)
        cell.setDate(date: date)

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let date = dateArray[indexPath.row]
    let title = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    let desc = descArray[indexPath.row]

    if notificationType == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TuvTavleViewCell") as! TuvTableViewCell
        cell.setTitle(title: title)
        cell.setDesc(desc: desc)
        cell.setDate(date: date)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewCell") as! NotificationViewCell
        cell.setTitle(title: title)
        cell.setDesc(desc: desc)
        cell.setDate(date: date)
        return cell
    }

}
```

plus consider having a configure method inside the cell class and pass the model to it , Also instead of having 3 arrays consider having a struct model like

```
struct Item {
   let title,desc,date:String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you're asking is

> How to get access of constant outside of if statement ?

This is actually not possible due to the scope modifier, anything declared within any type of closures loses it's scope when you get out of that closure.

So no you cant access anything declared inside an  `if` statement  out of that statement.

Now for your case how to solve the current problem, you have two options to do.

You can declare each `cell` out of the `if` or you can handle each one inside it's case.

You can even take this to another level by applying some protocols, and for that i will show you a simple example.

First of all you need this `protocol` and you need to confirm to it in your custom cells classes,

```
   protocol ConfigurableCell {
    func set(title: String)
    func set(desc: String)
    func set(date: Date)
   }
```

Confirming `class TuvTableViewCell: ConfigurableCell` and `class NotificationViewCell: ConfigurableCell`

Then you can do something like this.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let date = dateArray[indexPath.row]
    let title = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    let desc = descArray[indexPath.row]
    var cell: ConfigurableCell

    if notificationType == 1  {
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TuvTavleViewCell") as! ConfigurableCell

    } else {
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotificationViewCell") as! ConfigurableCell
    }
    cell.set(date: date)
    cell.set(desc: desc)
    cell.set(title: title)
}
```

As you see this will allow me to use the functions out side the `if` however according to the answer of your question i still didn't declared the `cell` inside the `if`, it's declared before.